# Split infinitives

Tags: infinitives

Was taught in grammar school that this was taboo (1950's, South Africa).
Today the split infinitive seems to be the standard in the USA.

Changing standard? It's always even that way in the US? 
What is the standard in England today?

Comment: Would you mind adding examples to your question?

Comment: See related threads, [_Are split infinitives grammatically incorrect, or are they valid constructs?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2117/are-split-infinitives-grammatically-incorrect-or-are-they-valid-constructs), [_Is using split infinitive allowed in formal English?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76366/is-using-split-infinitive-allowed-in-formal-english), [_Split infinitives—did Old English have them?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214781/split-infinitives-did-old-english-have-them),

Comment: and [_Why is the usage of split infinitives so controversial?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252068/why-is-the-usage-of-split-infinitives-so-controversial).

Comment: Infinitives in Old English were single words so the issue did not arise.

Comment: Split infinitives are rather like parallel fifths in composing - a matter of aesthetics.

Comment: @mikeagg Got a reference for that? [This page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Old_English/Verbs#The_infinitives) indicates that Old English had *tō* infinitives.

Comment: I suspect many school shibboleths originated as good writing advice: splitting an infinitive *can* lead to ambiguity; the active voice *can* be stronger than the passive voice; a sentence *can* be better worded when it does not start with a conjunction. It may be the case particularly with unskilled or novice writers. But that never made *all* instances substandard; George Eliot ends sentences with prepositions, Shakespeare used the singular *they*, and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's so old it makes the pyramids look brand new.

Comment: Many argue that there may be changing standards in regard to split infinitives. Standards in the UK and USA may be changing at different rates. Yet Michael votes "to close this question". Makes no sense to me

Comment: @curiousdannii I was wrong there. I misunderstood what Tom Chivers was saying in his [excellent article](http://blogs.telegraph.co.uk/news/tomchiversscience/100166631/to-go-boldly-why-splitting-infinitives-is-a-sacred-duty/) on split infinitives.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there was never a time that split infinitives were not used.  But some pedants invented the rule anyway, reasoning that English grammar should be more like that ideal of ideals, Latin grammar.  (In Latin, an infinitive is a single word, so of course one cannot split it.)

Comment: This is the best answer to this question, full stop.

Answer (score 0):

Language evolves. There used to be a rule against it, but now we're allowed to boldly go where no one has gone before.

Comment: Even when there was a rule, there were [examples of its use](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22to+boldly+go%22&lr=lang_en&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:01/01/1800,cd_max:31/12/1900&tbm=bks&gws_rd=cr&ei=YruPVs-wGYbbU7u9kYAN)

Comment: It was never a rule of grammar, only a rule of grammarians.

Comment: Great responses!